# Securing Blazor WASM and API with Auth0. CORS Policy issue

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, blazor, auth0, blazor-webassembly

I've been following the tutorial at Auth0 for securing a Blazor WASM and API with Aut0, which is found here --> https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/

Securing the app works fine, but adding the API gives me issues. As soon as I add the authenticate attribute to the API Controller it results in this:

> fetchdata:1 Access to fetch at
> 'https://localhost:7226/weatherforecast' from origin
> 'https://localhost:7298' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I've added a policy to allow the app in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7298").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

I've played around with the program.cs and also added app.UseCors before authentication/authorization (as a provided solution I found online), which then results in another issue.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
>
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON
> token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 0. System.Text.Json.JsonException: The input does
> not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid
> JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 0.

That error seems to indicate an issue with the bearertoken not being set, but it is setup using BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", client =>
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7226");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

I've added the project to GitHub, if more details on the code is of interest
https://github.com/obrungot/BlazorAuthenticationPlayGround.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddCors doesn't actually do anything except for adding a policy. It's not using that policy until you specify it somewhere. You can specify a global policy by using `app.UseCors("Open")`, add the policy to the endpoint routing e.g.  `app.MapGet("/test", () => Results.Ok("test")).RequireCors("Open")` or for controllers by using an attribute like `[EnableCors("Open")]`.

That you received a 401 suggested that Cors in general seems to work, however Cors also needs explicit permission to keep the Authorization header. This is done by adding "AllowCredentials()" to the policy like this:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:7298")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
    );
});
```

I hope this helps!

---

Edit:

Sorry. I somehow missed the github repository link. The reason why it doesn't work is that BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler is meant for hosting the API within the BaseAddress of the app. So in your case only calls to https://localhost:7298/ will include the token. You might either choose to host the API together with the app in the same process (this can be set up by choosing "ASP.NET Core Hosted" in the template) or use a custom AuthorizationMessageHandler which you can learn about here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-authorizationmessagehandler-class

In your case this would look like this:

```cs
public class ApiAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public ApiAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager navigationManager) : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(new[] { "https://localhost:7226" });
    }
}
```

When it comes to the cors the order is important

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```

If set up like that "[EnableCors("Open")]" on the controller should work.

Comment: Thank you for your feeback. I've added the following in Program.cs > app.MapControllers().RequireCors("Open");, but it still fails on CORS policy. Adding the attribute to the Controller did also have no effect.

Comment: Did you also add AllowCredentials as mentioned?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't change anything. However, I added app.UseRouting() and it now seems to resolve the cors issue. It does however give me a 401, (not authorized)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to check the github repository and see if you could get it to work?

Comment: Thanks! Your guidance and the link you provided made me make the final adjustments to make it work. Really appreciate it